# considering a String in a field as a DAX Measure in filters

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I need your expertise in solving this requirement?
I have a below 3 tables, Table contains the Measure stored as a String in backend.

Table_1:
ParentID (Num)  Parent_Name Formula (DAX Measure given as a written as a String)
1   Complex_1   = Calculate(Sum(Table_2[X]-Sum(Table_2[Y]))
2   Complex_2   =Calculate(Sum(Table_3[A] * Sum(Table_3[B]))

Table_2
Date    Parent_ID   X   Y
10.11.2022  1   60  45
11.11.2022  1   85  60
12.11.2022  1   30  20
13.11.2022  1   45  12

Table_2:
Date    Parent_ID   A   B
10.11.2022  2   60  50
11.11.2022  2   80  60
12.11.2022  2   30  20
13.11.2022  2   45  12

How do we evaluate a String in Formula column of Table_1 as a DAX_Measure, which should return me the result by evaluating it as a measure ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @communty, 
Hello, I tried to explain it other way... perhaps its clear now... DAX measure stored a String in a Column, in Power BI Desktop How do I evaluate the String as an Measure